# Design a specific situation in laravel ( many to many relationship)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7, laravel-query-builder

I want to ask about a specific situation..

I have 3 models :

**Store**

**Price**

**Product**

I have to set a specific price for a store on a specific product..

for example :

if I have product A that costs 100$ , I want to set it as 50$ for store A , 80$ for Store B ...etc

what I did is I created many-many relationship between Store and Price

and I stored product_id in pivot table...

like below

**Store.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Store\Models;
use App\Modules\Store\Models\Price;


class Store extends Model
{



    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Price::class,'store_prices');

    }

}
```

**Price.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Store\Models;

use App\Modules\Store\Models\Store;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Price extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['price'];

    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'store_prices');
    }

}
```

**StorePrice.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Store\Models;

use App\Modules\Product\Models\Product;
use App\Modules\Store\Models\Price;
use App\Modules\Store\Models\Store;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StorePrice extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['store_id', 'price_id', 'product_id'];
    protected $table = 'store_prices';

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class, 'store_id');
    }

    public function price()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Price::class, 'price_id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }

}
```

is this logically true ?

if it is , how can I group a price by product and show the related stores ?

otherwise I hope u can give maybe better propositions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need StorePrice Model. You just modify one of two models and add withPivot('product_id') like this

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'store_prices')->witPivot('product_id');
```

Regard to grouping, you can make if as a normal query which joins three tables ( store, pice and pivot) then group results based on product_id